# Remove specific word from string jquery

Tags: javascript

I have a string like : **Current year | Frequency**

Now i want to only **Current year**.
how can i do that ?

Here is my full string like : **Date range: Current year | Frequency: Daily**
i want to Current year & daily from this string.

Comment: show your attempt.

Comment: I just use like :  var saveRes = result.filterArr[i].filters_str;
                        str =  saveRes.replace('|','');
                        str = saveRes.split(":");

Comment: Not sure why you need jQuery to remove a word from a string. Also not sure why it is labeled as PHP. I guess more details would help.

Comment: I m replacing "|" from string but nothing happen

Comment: SHOW YOUR CODE.

Comment: @epascarello :      var saveRes = result.filterArr[i].filters_str; in this variable i have string like ::  Date range: Current year | Frequency: Daily

Comment: You said you are replacing `|`,  show it.

Comment: Seems like this is an actual X|Y problem. Where you are doing one thing, but you actually want something else. Seems like you have a list of filters are you are trying to get the values.

Comment: i want just  Current year  & Daily  from string how can i get it?

Comment: Just split the string on `|` and after that on `:`? https://jsfiddle.net/xvnwzm0p/

Comment: "*remove word"* `str = str.replace(/old_word/g, "new_word")` to remove, `new_word` == `""`.  You have to make sure you *set* your string.   `str.replace()` on its own will not update the `str`

Comment: In your comment `str = saveRes.replace('|',''); str = saveRes.split(":")` - the second `str=saveRes.split` overwrite the first change.  Use `str = str.split(":")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to parse it out. I would not rdo string replacement. I would match it and turn it into something that you can look up by key. I would use a Map.

```js
var filtersString = "Date range: Current year | Frequency: Daily";

var filters = new Map(filtersString.split(/\s?\|\s?/).map(function (v){
  return v.split(/:\s/);
}));

console.log(filters.get('Date range'));
console.log(filters.get('Frequency'));
```

Comment: thanks its working fine.. and how can i do same thing using php